# Proof of Kummer's theorem regarding regular primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading a proof of the above stated theorem ([see here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ila/Kummer.pdf)), and I am in need of clarification for a step in the main proof (page 7 in the above link).

Briefly outlining, (asumming $p$ is a prime greater than 3) it states to suppose that $x \equiv y \equiv -z$ (mod $p$). Substituting into the given equation ($x^p+y^p=z^p$) gives the congurence:

$-2z \equiv -2z^p \equiv x^p+y^p = z^p \equiv z \text{ (mod }p), \hspace{0.5in} (1)$

(Where these equivalences are all due to Fermat's little theorem.) This then implies that $3z \equiv 0$ (mod $p$), contradicting the fact that $p>3$ and an earlier assumption that $(p,z)=1$.

Okay, so this is fine and intuitive, and results in a reduction of our assumption, to $x \equiv y \not\equiv -z$. However, in the next line, the author says that exchanging $y$ and $-z$ in equation one "gives another counter example satisfying assumptions" and shows that we cannot hav $x \equiv y$ (mod $p$). But from context, it doesn't. I take it to mean: assume $x \equiv y \not\equiv -z$, and then $-y \equiv (-y)^p = x^p+(-z)^p \equiv x-z \equiv 2y$ (leading to the same result as determined from $(1)$). So if you're assuming $x \equiv y$, for this to be satisfied, you would have to have that $z\equiv -y$ which you have literally just discounted from happening.

I understand the importance of this result for the remaining proof, so essentially I would just like the above to explained a bit more clearly,to show why you could not have results (pretending they were still viable) where $x \equiv y$ (mod $p$)

Comment: If $x$ and $-z$ are incongruent, exchange $y$ and $-z$ and then $y$ and $y$ are incongruent.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer How can $y$ and $y$ be incongruent ?

Comment: Well, they can if they try real hard.

Comment: Okay, unsure of what it means for something to be incongruent to itself, but following your suggestion gives the following: $x^p+(-z)^p = (-y)^p \implies x-z\equiv -y$ (mod $p$). Then as we know that $z \not\equiv 0$ (mod $p$), this then implies that $x \not\equiv -y$ (mod $p$). However, $-y \not\equiv y$ (mod $p$), so I do not see how this leads to a solution

Comment: If x is not congruent to -z and if you switch -z and y, then x is not congruent to y,.